# Converting NSDictionary to JSON in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

i want to generate a JSON in Objective C , below is an example, one dictionary which has some fields, and within that dictionary i want to add another dictionary. i.e. Student dictionary can have subjects dictionary(which can have multiple items.

```
{
    "student": {
        "name": "b",
        "std": "d",
        "subjects": [{"id":"1","id":"2","id":"3"}]
}}
```

I am trying using NSJSONSerialization , i tried first creating json string of subjects dictionary but, after converting final JSON of main dictionary its showing (Slash) which is breaking json. i added subjects inside main dictionary then after converting its showing subjects json starting with **(**

Any suggestion what m i missing?

Thanks

Comment: show the code you used and the bad JSON output

Comment: If subjects is a dictionary it shouldn't have the square brackets

Answer (score 6):

Use NSJSONSerialization :

```
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionaryOrArrayToOutput 
                  options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
```

**Reference : https://stackoverflow.com/a/9020923/3222713**

And for your "slash" problem : https://stackoverflow.com/a/19651309/3222713

Comment: Instead of posting a link to another question and quoting an answer from that question, you should vote to close this question as a duplicate.