# NSJSONSerialization is changing the date separator from yyyy/MM/dd to yyyy\/MM\/dd

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json, ios10

```
NSString *date = [userDefaults objectForKey:KEY_FORM7_DECLARATION_DATE];
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:date, @"DATE",nil]
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary options:0 error:&error];
NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

When I do `NSLog(@"%@", date)` It shows me `2016/10/30`
But When I try to print `NSLog(@"%@", result)`  the date changes to `2016\/10\/30`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Paulw11 I even tried to write the json to text file but it shows the same.

Comment: Can you tell me what is the value for [userDefaults objectForKey:KEY_FORM7_DECLARATION_DATE]

Comment: It is String format of date i.e., "2016/10/10" @himanth

Comment: try like this                  NSString *date =  [userDefaults objectForKey:KEY_FORM7_DECLARATION_DATE];
                    NSString *main = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"DATE\":\"%@\"}",date];
    NSData *mainData = [main dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@",[[NSString alloc]initWithData:mainData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

Comment: Did you tried that?

Comment: @himanth It is of no use because i need to add it to the dictionary with my other parameters so that I will be able to do NSJSONSerialization but hey thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it's intended behaviour of `NSJSONSerialization`: [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19651009/how-to-prevent-nsjsonserialization-from-adding-extra-escapes-in-url)

For your simple case I can only come up with simple workaround: serialize the JSON with substitution sign and then use serialized string as a format:

```
let dateString = "2016/10/30"
var dict = ["DATE": "%@"]

do {
    let data = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dict, options: NSJSONWritingOptions(rawValue: 0))
    let format = String(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    let result = String(format: format, dateString)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```