# Why is JSONSerialization omitting the forwards slash in JSON String?

Tags: swift, nsjsonserialization

The incoming JSON from MockURL200Session produces a value of `2017-11-25 09:47:18 Etc/GMT`.

```
class MockURL200Session: URLSessionProtocol {
    var nextDataTask = MockURLSessionDataTask()
    var nextData: Data?
    var nextError: Error?

    func httpURLResponse(request: NSURLRequest) -> URLResponse {
        return HTTPURLResponse(url: request.url!, statusCode: 200, httpVersion: "HTTP/1.1", headerFields: nil)!
    }

    func dataTask(with request: NSURLRequest, completionHandler: @escaping DataTaskResult) -> URLSessionDataTaskProtocol {
        let json = ["expires_date": "2017-11-25 09:47:18 Etc/GMT"]
        nextData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: [])
        completionHandler(nextData, httpURLResponse(request: request), nextError)
        return nextDataTask as URLSessionDataTaskProtocol
    }
}
```

However, once it arrives on the client side the forward slash simply disappears and becomes `2017-11-25 09:47:18 Etc GMT`

```
self.httpClient.post(url: url) { (data, response, error) in
   let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as! Dictionary<String, Any>
}
```

How can I prevent it or escape it?

Comment: It seems that the issue happens server-side, since if you decode the encoded JSON data using `JSONSerialization`, the output is correct. If you send the same request from Postman, do you receive a correct response?

Comment: Server side works actually ok. It's the mock, that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

In `dataTask()`, your call to `JSONSerialization.data()` is escaping that forward slash when it decodes. You can see it in `nextData` before you return from `dataTask()`. Somewhere on its journey back to the client side, the `\/` combination is being removed. I would guess it's when you try to decode the server response. Now that you know what's happening, you can find the solution to the rest of your problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47076329/swift-string-escaping-when-serializing-to-json-using-codable), or if not, google something like "swift jsonserialization escape slash". Best of luck to you.