# Why does encoding a String with JSONEncoder adds a backslash?

Tags: ios, swift, encoding

Using:

```
let data = try! post.jsonData()
let dict = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [String:Any]
```

(force unwrapping for the sake of simplicity)

I receive this:

```
{
  "message" : "Some message",
  "media" : [
    {
      "type" : "jpeg",
      "url" : "storage\/thumb_QEHzApawkkMq3N2IYFhwLRUxhHlJd3rJK1NyCqvB.jpeg"
    }
  ]
}
```

instead of this ( note the backslash for the media.url )

```
{
  "message" : "Some message",
  "media" : [
    {
      "type" : "jpeg",
      "url" : "storage/thumb_QEHzApawkkMq3N2IYFhwLRUxhHlJd3rJK1NyCqvB.jpeg"
    }
  ]
}
```

I expect to get the JSON formatted the way the object is, without that annoying backslash as the API will not accept it,

What can it be?

Comment: dupe of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47076329/swift-string-escaping-when-serializing-to-json-using-codable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From json.org:

> A string is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, wrapped in
>   double quotes, using backslash escapes. A character is represented as
>   a single character string. A string is very much like a C or Java
>   string.

[image: JSON String]

You can also red this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27516892/614065

Comment: for my question, how do I convert the url string the way I need it ?

Comment: You can replace `\/`with`/`.

Comment: well, obviously I can do that. I can manually replace "\/", but that is not a clean solution for Swift.

Comment: dupe of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47076329/swift-string-escaping-when-serializing-to-json-using-codable