# AFNetworking serializes forward slash making the JSON payload invalid

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, afnetworking-2

I am using `AFNetworking` 2.0.

In `AFNetworking`, `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` object has an API:

```
(AFHTTPRequestOperation *)POST:(NSString *)URLString
                    parameters:(id)parameters
                       success:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject))success failure:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure
```

It accepts NSDictionary as params for the JSON Payload which we wish to 'POST' to the server. In my payload I have following key-value pair:

`"buttonActionParam":"/catalog/special/international-calling"`

Posting this payload server returns invalid JSON. Looking at the payload on the server side I realized that AFNetworking is actually  sending:

`"buttonActionParam":"\/catalog\/special\/international-calling".`

I know that `AFNetworking` library uses `NSJSONSerialization`'s class method `-dataWithJSONObject:`, which causes this. My question is:

Q. How to work around this issue?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question: you're saying that you're trying to send "buttonActionParam":"/catalog/special/international-calling", and this is exactly what is being sent by AFNetworking, so what's the problem?

Comment: Edited my question. Had to put escape characters. :)

Comment: The `NSData` that comes out of `NSJSONSerialization` isn't quite the same as what you're seeing on the server side - it shows `{"buttonActionParam":"\/catalog\/special\/international-calling"}` in my hex editor. I wonder if it's a character encoding issue - looks like the server is  sticking in an extra escape \ for some reason.

Comment: @RichTolley I edited what is coming out of NSJSONSerialization. I am looking for `{"buttonActionParam":"/catalog/special/international-calling"}` and not `{"buttonActionParam":"\/catalog\/special\/international-calling"}`

Answer (score 1):

This is know problem. It actually behaves as designed (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/20448342/669586).

There are 3 possible solution:

1. Make your server aware of the possibility that strings can be escaped. In general, this is the best solution.
2. Use a different JSON encoder (e.g. [SBJson](http://www.sbjson.org/)) and encode the object to `NSData` instead of using AFNetworking default serializer.
3. Encode using `NSJSONSerialization` and then convert the resulting data to a `NSString` (using `NSUTF8StringEncoding`), sanitize it and convert it back to `NSData`. Again, you have to do that before giving the object to AFNetworking.

The best way to implement 2 or 3 is setting a custom `requestSerializer` on the `AFHTTPSessionManager` instance. For example, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30802624/669586) for an example of implementing 3 (note it's in Swift).

Comment: #2 will work only if SBJson is used after AFNetworking.
#3 I tried before posting. Doesn't work.

I will try #1.

Comment: @DeborshiSaha Nope, it mostly about how you set up the serializer. If you don't let AFNetworking use its default request serializer (which uses `NSJSONSerialization`), then you have no problem.